# Backbiting about someone

Tags: backbiting

I was talking about my ex aunty to my friends I didn’t mention her name I just said ex aunty and now I regret talking about her and I don’t have any way to get back to her and ask for forgiveness but if I have a way I feel like if I ask for forgiveness she’ll be angrier what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Always ask for forgiveness, even if she gets mad at you it's for the sake of Allah. But if you do know that it's going to cause major problems in the future, the intention is all that matters. Ask Allah to make it easier for you and to guide you to the right answer. Salam.

Comment: Thanks but I don’t have any way to get to her no number nothing